# If $f(1) = i$ what is $f(i)$ for a function with $|f(z)| \leq K|z|$ ? GATE 2011

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function s.t. $|f(z)| < K|z|$, $\forall$ $z \in \mathbb{C}$, for some $K > 0$. If $f(1) = i$ what is the value of $f(i)$ and **why**? The value of $f(i)$ will be one of these four followings.

1. 1
2. -1
3. i
4. -i

My intuition is $i$ i.e. 3. I am imagining some boundedness property like Liouville's theorem, but I do not know accurate result(s) and proof(s). I am more interested in **why** part. Please add sufficient reference.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your problem does not make sense for $z=0$.

Comment: Why problem has no sense for $z = 0$? It gives $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: The inequality you wrote is strict <

Comment: Error fixed....

Comment: Duplicate question but answer is better in this time.

Comment: ... so when this is (rightly) closed, this answer should be copied there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f(z)/z is bounded. Hence, it must be constant. Thus, f(1)/1 = f(i)/i. This gives use that f(i)= if(1) = -1.

Why is f(z)/z entire? Well, f(z) is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$ and so we can write it as power series $\sum{a_{n}z^{n}} = a_{0} + a_{1}z + a_{2}z^{2} + ...$ Since for all $z$ arbitrarily close to $0$ we get that $ f(z)/z = a_{0}/z + a_{1} +  a_{2}z + ... $ is bounded by $K$, we must have $a_{0} = 0$. Thus, $f(z)/z = a_{1} + a_{2}z + ...$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I think you should add more to your answer. Why must a bounded function which is only defined on a proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$ be constant?

Comment: $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ is bounded, trivially. But for being a constant it must be entire. So why you are saying $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ is entire. Add it with the proof.